# Scan string into an ArrayList

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to scan some Strings (without ,) and print them out (with ,).
May I know how should I change my code?

> Example: Test input: Apple Pen Water
>
> Correct output: [Apple, Pen, Water]
>
> Current code output: [Apple Pen Water]

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(sc.hasNext()){
            yourList.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(yourList);
        
    } 
 }
```

Comment: don't use the default `toString` of `ArrayList`

Comment: Problem is the use of `.nextLine()` method which reads the space-separated words as one string. Either use `.next()` method or read user input in  a string variable, split the string on space character and then add each word in the ArrayList.

Comment: What do you think *line* means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inputting the entire line as a single string instead of separate strings:

```java
while(sc.hasNext()){
    yourList.add(sc.next()); // next() instead of nextLine
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print words from list separated with comma, use String.join:

```
System.out.println(String.join(",", yourList));
```